# Dropdown Can't be sorted

Tags: php, html, mysql, datatable

I'm having trouble sorting a dropdown.

So far my datatable can sort the ID, Name, Position, and Application Date as shown in the picture.
But my datatable can't sort the category. How can I sort the category? Your help would be appreciated.

Here is the code that I use to show the data in the datatable.

[Here is a picture of my user interface](https://ibb.co/cBx9AG)
Sorry for using a link, I'm newbie and not allowed to use pictures yet.

```
<table class="table isSearch table-bordered table-striped"  id="table" cellspacing="0">                     
    <thead>          
        <tr class="table-heads ">
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th> <!-- Table Header -->
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Application Date</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Arrange Interview</th>
                <th>Online Interview</th></tr>

        </thead>

        <tbody>
              <?php
                include"../database.php";
              $query="SELECT user.name, job_application.created_at, 
              job.job_name, job_application_id, status_id, email, skypeid 
              FROM user, job_application, job 
              WHERE user.user_id = job_application.user_id 
              AND job.job_id = job_application.job_id 
              ORDER BY STATUS_ID ASC"; 
              $result=mysqli_query ($connect,$query);    

              while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                  { 
                  echo 
                "<tr><form action='update_status.php?id=".$data['job_application_id']."' method='post'>";
                echo"<td>".$data['job_application_id']."</td>";
                echo"<td>".$data['name']."</td>";
                echo"<td>".$data['job_name']."</td>";
                echo"<td>".$data['created_at']."</td>"; 
                echo"<td>
                <select name='status'>
                    <option name='status' value='1'";?><?php if ($data['status_id']=='1') {echo " selected";}echo "> Waiting </option>
                    <option name='status' value='2'";?><?php if ($data['status_id']=='2') {echo " selected";}echo "> Rejected </option>
                    <option name='status' value='3'";?><?php if ($data['status_id']=='3') {echo " selected";}echo "> Interviewed </option>
                    <option name='status' value='4'";?><?php if ($data['status_id']=='4') {echo " selected";}echo "> Hired </option>
                </select>
                    <br>
                    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Save'>
                    </form>
                </td>";                
                echo"<td>
               <center><a href='email.php?email=".$data['email']."&id=".$data['job_application_id']." 'target='_blank' style='border-radius:30px' class='btn btn-secondary btn-sm'>E-Mail</a><center>
                </td>";
                echo"<td><center><a href='skype:".$data['skypeid']."?call' style='border-radius:30px' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'><img src='assets/images/skype.png' width='25 height='13'>Call</a><center></td>";
                echo"</tr>"; 
                  }
                  ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to create a local array in the javascript

```
          var categories = [];
```

and push the data from the database to this variable

```
          categories.push({}) // you can push the object or the string
```

and then define the sort function with your custom logic https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp .

```
           function sortTheCategory();
```

Now call this function based on the event happening with the header column.